# Why is POST data truncated by PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, post, truncate, missing-data

I have a pretty big form with many-many items in it. After upgrading to PHP 7, in the new environment some of the POST elements are not received by the server. The `$_POST` array is not empty, it contains many elements, but some of the elements from the end of the `$_POST` array is missing.

No error messages appear.

Increasing `post_max_size` in `php.ini` (from 8M to 128M) did not help. The data structure itself is not too big, less than 400k, so this shouldn't be the reason.

Why can this be?

Comment: Define `many-many items`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois it was ~2000. The exact number was not relevant at the time of the question, the point was that it was more than 1000. :)

Comment: many-many isn't defined nor does it mean specifically more than X. Directly putting in the numbers instead using vague terms is far more productive. But eh, this is a question from almost two years ago.

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 5.3.9. a new php.ini setting exists called max_input_vars. It determines how many items can be used from the received data. By default it is 1000 which means that only the first 1000 items from $_POST will be used.

So, if increasing the post_max_size does not help then try to increase max_input_vars from 1000 to 5000 or whatever you need.

More info: [PHP Manual for max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)

Comment: imo, this would be worth a look at. It may have been set higher than the default in the previous version PHP.INI file and not yet increased in the PHP7 ini.file. Not sure why the down-vote was required.

Comment: I don't agree with the down-vote either. 

Yes, too many items in $_POST is not good but if you have to upgrade PHP version under your or someone else's legacy code then you don't necessarily have enough resource to modernise the structure of the code. Just consider the time requirement of re-testing and the potential consequences of a failure.